# How to read any CSV file from my pcl folder in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.essentials

I have one CSV file in my PCL folder, i want to get the path of that file so i can read the files using File.ReadAllLine().
Here is the code I have been used not not getting the file, as i have changed the file to the embedded resources
I want this in string[] lines.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("PrinterTestSample.Csv.UserData.csv");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to get a stream from the assembly where the embedded resource is. Below a sample code on how to read it.

```cs
        // replace App with a class that is in the project where the embedded resource is.
        var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        // replace App3 with the namespace where your file is
        var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("App3.XMLFile1.xml");

        var lines = new List<string>();

        using var reader = new StreamReader(stream);

        while (reader.ReadLine() is { } line)
        {
            lines. Add(line);
        }
```